# How to make a function that swaps 3 characters in a string?

Tags: swift, string

For example, if I had a string RedSox and wanted to change it to SoxRed?
I'm thinking it would be something like :

```
     func swapString (String: String) -> String {

  var stringReplaced = String

  var result = stringReplaced.Select(x=> x == 'A' ? 'B' : (x=='B' ? "A" : x)).ToArray()

  stringReplaced = String(result)

    return stringReplaced
  }
```

Comment: What if the word does not have 6 characters? What if it has more? What if it  has *less*?

Comment: Yea thats the thing, it will swap out every pair of three characters

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: What would be the expected result for "A" or "1234"?

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear enough, the function will take a string and swap every 3 characters if possible for example : 123abc becomes abc123

Comment: Your question is still very unclear. Do you want to split your string into groups of 6 characters each and swap the first 3 with the last 3? If so, what happen when there are less than 6 characters in the group?

Comment: What is the output of the following input:
abcba, a, abcdcba

Answer (score 0):

this function takes the last 3 characters of a string and appends them to the beginning, there are definitely less verbose ways of doing this but it works. it will throw an error if passed a string with < 3 characters.

```
import UIKit

let string = "RedSox"


func changeString ( _ string : String) -> String {
    var characters : Array<Character> = []
    for character in string.characters {
        characters.append(character)
    }

    var characters2 : Array<Character> = []
    var position = characters.count - 3

    while position < characters.count {
         characters2.append(characters[position])
         position += 1
    }

    characters.removeLast()
    characters.removeLast()
    characters.removeLast()
    characters2.append(contentsOf: characters)
    return (String(characters2))
}


var newString = changeString(string)
print (newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the methods which the `String` class already provides.
It's always a good idea putting these kind of "helper" methods in an extension.

```
// Define String extension
extension String {

    func swappedString(count swapCount: Int) -> String {
        guard self.characters.count > swapCount else {
            return self
        }

        let index = self.index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -swapCount)
        let first = self.substring(from: index)
        let second = self.substring(to: index)

        return first + second
    }
}

// Use it
"RedSox".swappedString(count: 3) //= SoxRed
```